# Filter Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I filter fields within an array that is inside of an object?

Sample:

```
{
  _index: "consult",
  _type: "user",
  _id: "TlgRL71xRyq-0guJTGA9WQ",
  _score: 1,
  _source: {
    token: "1113",
    userlist: [
      {
        id: "1",
        nome: "Mark"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        nome: "Joe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object's properties by using a fully qualified path (e.g. "dot notation").  For example, here is a Term filter looking for a specific id value:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "term": {
                  "userlist.id": 1
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```